# ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)

Tags: 22.04, 23.04, ldap, openldap

I am trying to configure LDAPS with Let's Encrypt, but I am keep getting this error: ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)

I am using Ubuntu 22.04

**Permissions on Certificates**

```
root@LDAPS:~/.acme.sh/ldaps.example.net_ecc# ls -l
total 45
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     2668 Jul 30 23:09 ca.cer
-rw-r--r-- 1 openldap openldap 4120 Jul 30 23:09 fullchain.cer
-rw-r--r-- 1 openldap openldap 1452 Jul 30 23:09 ldaps.example.net.cer
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      582 Jul 30 23:09 ldaps.example.net.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      473 Jul 30 23:07 ldaps.example.net.csr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      189 Jul 30 23:07 ldaps.example.net.csr.conf
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap  227 Jul 30 23:07 ldaps.example.net.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      429 Jul 30 23:20 tls.ldif
```

**Contents of tls.ldif**

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /root/.acme.sh/ldaps.example.net_ecc/fullchain.cer
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /root/.acme.sh/ldaps.example.net_ecc/ldaps.example.net.cer
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /root/.acme.sh/ldaps.example.net_ecc/ldaps.example.net.key
-
replace: olcTLSVerifyClient
olcTLSVerifyClient: never
```

**Apparmor**

```
nano /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.slapd

/root/.acme.sh/ldaps.example.net_ecc/ r,
/root/.acme.sh/ldaps.example.net_ecc/ * r
```